# IOS ContactUI navigate back to app after edit

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin IOS app I open the ContactUI with the following code:

```
var contact = new AddressBookService().GetCNContactById(addressbookId);
var view = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact(contact);
view.Editing = true;

// Display the view
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var vc = window.RootViewController;
while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
{
    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
}

var navController = vc as UINavigationController;
if (navController != null)
{
    vc = navController.ViewControllers.Last();
}
vc.PresentViewController(new UINavigationController(view), true, null);
```

I wrap it in a `INavigationController` because without it won't load. There is the following message printed to the output:

```
[CNUI ERROR] Contact view delayed appearance timed out
```

The Edit Dialog is displayed correctly. But after I click on Save I come to the details view:

[image]

As you can see is the second problem, that there is no back button. So the only way to come back to my app is to kill the app and start again.
Is there a way to navigate directly back to my app after I saved the contact? Or to wrap the ContactUI in my current ViewController so that the `TabBar` is still visible below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `CNContactViewControllerDelegate` and use the `DidComplete` delegate of CNContactViewController. `DidComplete` will be fired when the "Done" button is clicked.

1. Set the delegate:

   ```
   var view = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact(contact);
   view.Delegate = new MyCNConatactViewControllerDelegate();
   ```
2. Implement the `DidComplete`, and dismiss the NavigationController which contains your CNContactViewController here:

   ```
   public class MyCNConatactViewControllerDelegate : CNContactViewControllerDelegate
   {

       public override void DidComplete(CNContactViewController viewController, CNContact contact)
       {
           viewController.NavigationController.DismissViewController(true, null);
       }

   }
   ```